# how to use value of curl in while loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop

even if status becomes "UP", while to be will be continue. why can't i use a variable in a loop as a condition?

```
export confup=false
export blup=false
timeout 30 bash <<EOF || false
while [[  $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.status') != "UP" ]];
do
if [[ $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.components."bridge.lock".status') == "UP" && \$blup == "false" ]]; then
    echo "true
    export blup=yes
fi
if [[ $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.components."Configuration converted".status') == "UP" && \$confup == "false" ]]; then
    echo "true"
    export confup=yes
fi
echo $( curl "http://0.0.0.0/" | jq -r '.status')
sleep 5
done 
EOF
```

Comment: Aside from the correct answer by Barmbar, I don't see a good reason why you want to use a here-DOC. It just unnecessarily complicates things and makes your code more difficult to maintain. BTW, since you are running the here-DOC as a childprocess, your changes of `blup` and `confup` won't be visible in your (parent) script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing `curl` each time through the loop. It's just being executed once and the result is substituted into the here-doc.

You should use a quoted here-doc so that the variables and command substitutions are not done on the original document. Then you also don't need to escape the `$` in `$blup` and `$confup`.

There's also no need to export these variables.

```
timeout 30 bash <<'EOF' || false
while [[  $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.status') != "UP" ]];
    do
    if [[ $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.components."bridge.lock".status') == "UP" && $blup == "false" ]]; then
        echo "true"
        blup=yes
    fi
    if [[ $( curl http://0.0.0.0/ | jq -r '.components."Configuration converted".status') == "UP" && $confup == "false" ]]; then
        echo "true"
        confup=yes
    fi
    echo $( curl "http://0.0.0.0/" | jq -r '.status')
    sleep 5
done 
EOF
```